# Time difference php/mysql need to format the output conditionally (4 small highlights required)

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to get difference of date/time from a field type datetime to "right now" using php and mysql as database

this code is working fine, returns the output beautifully ok as required

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('mydate1');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%d days %h hours %i minutes');
```

that is ok so far, no issues as this function is for php 5.3 and i have it on server

my need is 4 small things actually

1) how to eliminate the need for days?
i want to have (25 hours 10 minutes) instead of (1 day 1 hours 10 minutes)

2) how i can make `$elapsed` be bold or colored if the value is more than 5 hours for example!? simple IF logic will not work as the output is not actually a predefined value...

3) if the days or hours are 0, then want to remove them!
- For example if showing (0 days 10 hours 40 mins) then no need to display the (0 days), should show (10 hours 40 mins) that is enough
 - Another example: 0 days 0 hours 45 minutes then to show only "45 minutes" no need for days and hours!

4) if output less than 5 minutes in total (0days 0 hours 1-5mins), then wanna make it show like "a while ago" only no need for any days, hours or minutes... then after 6 minutes.. go like "6 mins"

shortly something like facebook!?

okay, what i searched tried is different combination of workarounds but never worked as you know this interval is for php 5.3 and still seem not widely used?

any hint for one or more parts of this long question is appreciated,

M, Derik

Comment: 1) and 3) contradicts each other.

Comment: no problem, wanna how to do that, it will be used in 2 different places! just trying to see which one will be better !?

Comment: what's your need actually? may be a different better approach can be made if you write your purpose.

Comment: here itachi, see the below answer of Mr Gokigooooks, it has the need and he covered it like almost all, will tweak the code to get the exact required stuff for my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried to answer all your questions. so read the comments because i didnt write numbers for the problems. sorry

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('mydate1');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$minutes = round(abs($datetime1 - $datetime2) / 60,2); //to calculate total time in MINUTES

if($minutes < 5) // for awhile ago problem.
    {
      return "awhile ago"; 
    }

elseif($minutes > 6 && < 60)
    {
       return $minutes." minutes ago"; //for 6 minutes and after.
    }

elseif($minutes>60) // for the hours..
{
    $hours = floor($final_time_saving / 60);
    $minutes = $final_time_saving % 60;
    $string = $hours. " hours and" . $minutes . " minutes ago.";

    if($hours>5) //for bolding characters after 
    { 
     return "<b>".$hours." hours and".$minutes." minutes ago.</b>"; //for bolding character
    }
    else
      return $hours." hours and".$minutes." minutes ago.";
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: perfect, answered most of my concerns obviously, appreciated dude

Comment: execuse me Gokigoooks please can you explain more about it? i am not able to get the final result variable this way :( sorry, please have a look and advise

Comment: hi again, my datetime field is in this way "2012-11-16 09:08:45" but i keep receiving this error:"Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int"
where to convert it? and how exactly? i've read a lot and treid a lot but nothing works yet :(

Comment: hey friend, try using adding a GMT in your date.

Comment: try a `datetime1 = strtotime("mydate1");` approach. do it with the second one, then it returns an int in seconds. so `$minutes = round(abs($datetime1 - $datetime2) / 60,2);` please try

Comment: hi again, i did this: $datetime1=strtotime(datefield);
$datetime2 = time(); but what i got is: Undefined variable: final_time_saving

Comment: ok i got it by removing the return and made it normal $variable then echo it later, don't know why return didn't work. thanks friend.